# 'xlsx' warning in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng, xlsx

My script is using `Prime UI (Angular)` table to export data as `xlsx`
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/export

Here are the working code

```
  exportExcel() {
    console.log('this.appResults.output.data=', this.appResults.output.data)
    import("xlsx").then(xlsx => {
      const worksheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(this.appResults.output.data);
      const workbook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
      const excelBuffer: any = xlsx.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
      this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, "Results");
    });
  }

  saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    import("file-saver").then(FileSaver => {
      let EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
      let EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
      const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
        type: EXCEL_TYPE
      });
      FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
    });
  }
```

And angular build time is relatively long, and with complain of the package whenever i use it

```
Lazy Chunk Files      | Names              |      Size
xlsx.js               | xlsx               |   1.69 MB
...
file-saver.js         | file-saver         |   4.17 kB

Build at: 2021-06-19T03:01:59.988Z - Hash: 40c0bb4716e62bd0dfa2 - Time: 65062ms
Warning: /....component.ts depends on 'file-saver'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /home/....component.ts depends on 'xlsx'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

How can I optimize (reduce) the build time and file size? I saw some post to suppress warning but it's not my intention.

Comment: You can't really reduce the build time. These libraries are not built to be moduled and are always compiled because ts has checks to do on them. If you want to be extreme about it create a separate library project, put them there. This way they'll only be compiled when you want them to but it seems like an overkill.